# Hibernate Cascade unable to persist Child entities and fails with Transient instance error

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a parent entity:

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
    })
    public class PCUser implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long id;

        @NotBlank
        private String firstName;

        private String lastName;

        @NotBlank
        @Email
        private String email;

        private String companyName = null;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pcUser", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Circuit> circuits = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
            circuit.setPCUser(this);
            circuits.add(circuit);
        }
    }
```

And a child entity:

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(uniqueConstraints={
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"userID", "name"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "circuitID")
    })
    public class Circuit implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long id;

        @NotBlank
        private String circuitID = CommonsUtil.randomAlphanumeric(10);

        @NotBlank
        private String name;

        @Embedded
        private NetworkEndpoint networkEndpoint;

        @NotNull
        private Boolean active;

        @NotNull
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "userID", nullable = false)
        private PCUser pcUser;
    }
```

I try to create a new *Circuit* by using the *addCircuit* method of *PCUser* in a service class:

```java
    public void createCircuit(PCUser pcUser, Circuit circuit) {
        validateCircuit(circuit);
        pcUser.addCircuit(circuit);
        pcUserRepository.save(pcUser);
        logCircuitCreation(circuit);
    }
```

But I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references
>   an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing: com.pcmap.commons.models.Circuit

Most suggestions for this problem is to use the Cascade type on the mapping so all child entities are saved beforehand when the parent is updated. But here I am already using it with *CascadeType.ALL* so what is going wrong?

**EDIT**:
Some more details showing *createCircuit* method is called from a REST controller.

```
@PostMapping(produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createCircuit(@Valid @RequestBody CircuitCreateRequest circuitCreateRequest,
                                            Principal principal) {
    circuitCreateRequest.clean();
    String username = principal.getName();
    PCUser pcUser = proxyCircuitUserRepository.findByAuth0UserID(username);
    if (pcUser == null)
        throw new PCUserNotFoundException();

    Circuit circuit = new Circuit();
    circuit.setName(circuitCreateRequest.getName());
    circuit.setRegionSlug(circuitCreateRequest.getRegionSlug());
    circuit.setCircuitType(ValuesUtil.getCircuitType(circuitCreateRequest.getCircuitType()));
    circuit.setPassword(circuitCreateRequest.getPassword());

    circuitManagerService.createCircuit(pcUser, circuit);

    CircuitIDResponse circuitIDResponse = new CircuitIDResponse();
    circuitIDResponse.setCircuitID(circuit.getCircuitID());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(circuitIDResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

And here are the methods *validateCircuit* and *checkCircuitLimit* called from *createCircuit*

```
private void validateCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
    if (circuit.getName() == null)
        circuit.setName(circuit.getCircuitID());
    if (circuit.getPassword() == null)
        circuit.setPassword(circuit.getCircuitID());
    circuit.setActive(true);

    NetworkEndpoint networkEndpoint = new NetworkEndpoint();
    networkEndpoint.setHostname(getHostname());
    networkEndpoint.setPort(junctionProperties.getPort());
    circuit.setNetworkEndpoint(networkEndpoint);

    if (circuit.getName() == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Circuit name");

    if (circuitRepository.findByNameIgnoreCaseAndPCUser(circuit.getName(),
            circuit.getPCUser()) != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Circuit with same name already exists");

    if (circuit.getPassword() == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid username/password");

    if (!validateRegionSlug(circuit.getRegionSlug()))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid regionSlug");

    if (circuit.getCircuitType() == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid CircuitType");
}

private void checkCircuitLimit(PCUser pcUser) {
    if (pcUser.getCircuits().size() > pcUser.getMaxCircuits())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Circuit max limit reached");
}
```

Comment: is it possible that you explicitly set the ID for the `circuit` you just created?

Comment: @Krisz I checked, it doesn't happen.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but it works for me. Could you edit the question with more details? Such as how do you obtain the PCUser, how do you create the circuit, etc.

Comment: @Krisz I have added some more details.

Comment: Thanks, though I wasn't able to spot any mistakes, there are a few things you could try. You could try to annotate your controller method with `Transactional` (from Spring, not JPA) - it's possible that you lose transactional context when calling your service method and your parent becomes unmanaged. If this fails, you could work around the issue by saving the child entity first, then saving the parent entity, though of course it's less than ideal. Otherwise you could create a minimal example on Github and I can take a look for you since I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try both the methods and let it be known here.

Comment: As the exception is cut of at the end, I guess you need to persist the `networkEndpoint `before cascading the Circuit.

Comment: @Manuel NetworkEndpoint is an embeddable entity so I think it isn't required to persist it beforehand.